# Resize Image with jQuery before append it to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi guys this is my code:

```
var new_container_element = 
    $("<div></div>").addClass("content content_loaded")
    .append($("<div></div>")
    .append($("<a></a>").attr("href", DefaultImageSrc)
    .append($("<img></img>").attr("src", DefaultImageSrc).addClass("thumb"))));
$(".container").append(new_container_element);
```

How can i resize this image before append it to `.container` for example `height=300 and width=500`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **.css( propertyName, value ):** Set one or more CSS properties for the set of matched elements.

You can use **[css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** function :

```
 .append($("<img></img>").css({width: '500px',heigth: '300px'})...
```

**Full code :**

```
var new_container_element = 
    $("<div></div>").addClass("content content_loaded")
    .append($("<div></div>")
    .append($("<a></a>").attr("href", DefaultImageSrc)
    .append($("<img></img>").css({width: '500px',heigth: '300px'})
    .attr("src", DefaultImageSrc).addClass("thumb"))));
$(".container").append(new_container_element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Erm, you really shouldn't been chaining like that. But you can specify the image dimensions using .css() or via .width() and .height().